# References for variants of many-sorted first-order logic treating truth values as just another sort

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic

It's possible to treat the sort of truth values as an explicit sort. For example, one algebraic approach to understanding propositional logics can be thought of as elevating the truth values to an explicit sort and using a unary (classical) predicate that picks our designated truth values $D(\square)$ as *our lifeline back to classical logic*.

The truth values $T$ of classical logic can be understood as [Boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)). I'm assuming that we'd be organizing our (classical) truth values into a Boolean algebra with a distinguished subset of designated truth values but would not have *a designatedness predicate at the syntactic level*.

I'm curious if there are any references on extensions of many-sorted first-order logic that make the set of truth values a *peer* with respect to the other domains and would allow, say, a function $f : T \to D_1$ where $D_1$ is a non-truth-value domain.

Noah Schweber asked [this question on Math Overflow about co-relations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325706/logic-with-co-relations-sources). Noah's motivating example is [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering), which can reflect arbitrary bits of syntax back into the entity domain. Noah has also identified some interesting technical problems in free variable management (that Andrej Bauer addresses, among other things, in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/325711/)).

I'm after a much more limited animal that just treats truth values the same way that non-truth-value domains are treated.